# Restkit Objective-C: Post request only works once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, drupal, restkit

I'm using Restkit to communicate with Drupal CMS. When I'm sending the
first request everything works fine: I'm getting the correct JSON-
string -> awesome. This is what the console says:

> 2011-06-24 23:00:48.344 MyApp[1399:207] Sending POST request to URL
>   http://mysite.com/myproject/services/rest/service_views/get.json. HTTP
>   Body: view_name=viewsname

If the app tries to send the same request again, nothing happens. None
of the delegate-methods get called. The console says:

> 2011-06-24 23:03:40.224 MyApp[1399:207] Sending GET request to URL
>   http://www.mysite.com/myproject/services/rest/service_views/get.json.
>   HTTP Body:

I'm doing all the Restkit stuff in a special-class (singleton), which
I keep as an instance variable of my view-controller. In the init-function of this
class I am doing this:

```
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager
objectManagerWithBaseURL:kBaseURLKey];
```

In my view-controller I'm calling a `- (void)pollForNewData` function,
which does the following:

```
RKObjectLoader* objectLoader = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath: kRessourceKey objectClass:[RKNotification class] delegate:self]; 
objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
objectLoader.params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects: @"view_name", @"viewsname", nil];
[objectLoader send];
```

Can anybody help me? Do I have to do something special after the first
response came? Is it possible to cancel a request (if the current view was left)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current RestKit source (~0.9.2+) doesn't seem to have loadObjectsAtResourcePath:objectClass:delegate: method.

You could use something like this:

```
// It's for logging in Drupal's user resource with RestKit.
// You can change the user bits to your need.

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
RKObjectMapping *currentUserMapping = [objectManager.mappingProvider objectMappingForKeyPath:@"currentUser"];

RKObjectLoader *objectLoader = [objectManager objectLoaderWithResourcePath:@"user/login" delegate:self];
objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
objectLoader.objectMapping = currentUserMapping;
objectLoader.params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"testuser", @"username",
                       @"testpass", @"password",
                       nil];
[objectLoader send];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've been searching for this the whole day! Thanks! One thing, `objectMappingForKeyPath:` is deprecated in 0.9.3, use `mappingForKeyPath:` instead :)